# How to get the eclipse installation/plugins directory or path

Tags: eclipse

How to get the Eclipse installation directory through programming in swt/java.
I actually want to get the plugins directory of the eclipse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update (January 2012)
[James Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73046/james-moore) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720214/how-to-get-the-eclipse-installation-plugins-directory-or-path/4720680#comment11434093_4720680) that the FAQ and API are quite old.

[`FileLocator.resolve(URL)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html) is now preferred to the deprecated `Platform.resolve()`.

As [this example](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/674114/) shows, you need to pass the actual resource (here a [bundle](http://eclipse.org/equinox/bundles/)), not the name of the resource, in order to resolve it:

```
private static URI locateFile(String bundle, String fullPath) {
  try {
    URL url = FileLocator.find(Platform.getBundle(bundle), new Path(fullPath), null);
    if(url != null)
      return FileLocator.resolve(url).toURI();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
  }
}
```

See also "[How to refer a file from jar file in eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5660242/6309)" for more.

---

Original answer (January 2011)

Maybe the FAQ "[How do I find out the install location of a plug-in?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_the_install_location_of_a_plug-in%3F)" can help here:

> You should generally avoid making assumptions about the location of a plug-in at runtime.
>   To find resources, such as images, that are stored in your plug-in’s install directory, you can use URLs provided by the `Platform` class. These URLs use a special Eclipse Platform protocol, but if you are using them only to read files, it does not matter.
>
> In Eclipse 3.1 and earlier, the following snippet opens an input stream on a file called `sample.gif` located in a subdirectory, called `icons`, of a plug-in’s install directory:

```
  Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(yourPluginId);
  Path path = new Path("icons/sample.gif");
  URL fileURL = Platform.find(bundle, path);
  InputStream in = fileURL.openStream();
```

> If you need to know the file system location of a plug-in, you need to use `Platform.resolve(URL)`. This method converts a platform URL to a standard URL protocol, such as HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP), or file.
>   Note that the Eclipse Platform does not specify that plug-ins must exist in the local file system, so you cannot rely on this method’s returning a file system URL under all circumstances in the future.
>
> In Eclipse 3.2, the preferred method seems to be:

```
  Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(yourPluginId);
  Path path = new Path("icons/sample.gif");
  URL fileURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
  InputStream in = fileURL.openStream();
```

Comment: Thanks for the above but I've a doubt.Consider I have an plug-in project named com.abhishek.html.test and inside it I've a folder named html carrying few html files. Now I want to read those html in plug-in, then which approach I should follow. Locally it works but how a plug-in will detect the folder named html ?

Comment: @Abhishek: I am not sure about the "locally it works". As opposed to what configuration exactly? Because your program should be able to detect the `html` folder in the plugin by getting the bundle and using `FileLocator`. It should return null (or throw an exception, I forgot which) if `html` don't exist within that plugin.

Comment: That FAQ entry is horrible.  3.[1,2] are ancient - why not talk about recent releases?  It recommends using Platform.resolve, but Platform.resolve is marked "Deprecated. use FileLocator.resolve(URL) instead"  And why in the world is a FAQ saying something like "the preferred method seems to be"?  Why qualify with such wishy-washy language?

Comment: @JamesMoore: good point. I have updated the answer in order to reflect the right API and added references to examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the plugin path :

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Comment: what Class is that 'this' object?

Comment: this - user defined class object In which the above code is used.for ex. if you have a class Myclass.java then the above code can be used like "Myclass.class.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();"